# Question related to how docker containers networking work

Tags: docker, networking, linux-containers

When we expose ports through docker its network path is as below

[Docker container network flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNtVk.png)

So when I run my container using below command

`docker run --rm -it --name server -p 45678:45678 ubuntu:14.04 bash`

Here we are basically mapping external-host-port : with internal container port correct?

Now inside the above container If I start netcat to listen to port 45678; Then any container should be able to connect with it using `nc <my-windows-hostname> 45678` right? However, it does not work.

I read about this and found out that we need to use `host.docker.internal` instead of windows-hostname.

My question is why so??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker for Windows (and Docker for Mac) utilizes a virtual machine with a Linux Kernel to provide runtime environment for linux containers.

This means that the containers do run on a separate host (with another name and IP) than your windows host, as describe din the illustration below below

```
|--------------------------------------------------------|
|  Windows host     |----------------------------------| |
|                   | Docker VM                        | |
|  docker cli       | |-------------|  |-------------| | |
|                   | | ContainerA  |  | ContainerB  | | |
|                   | |             |  |             | | |
|                   | |-------------|  |-------------| | |
|                   |----------------------------------| |
|--------------------------------------------------------|
```

The docker cli runs on windows, but all containers run inside the Docker VM.

When you run the command
`docker run --rm -it --name containerA -p 45678:45678 ubuntu:14.04 bash` port 45678 on the Docker VM is forwarded to port 45678 in containerA .

In addition the Docker CLI takes care of forwarding port 45678 on the windows host to the Docker VM. The result of this is that when you use `localhost:45678` or `<my-windows-hostname>:45678` from your windows machine, you will end up on the container through the chain:

```
<my-windows-hostname>:45678 -> <docker VM>:45678 -> ContainerA:45678
```

What you are trying to do is to access another container through a published port from *another* container, not the windows host. In order to do so you would need to have the internal hostname or IP of the Docker VM rather than the windows host. This is what you can use `host.docker.internal` for.

From the [Docker for Windows Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/networking/#use-cases-and-workarounds)

> The host has a changing IP address (or none if you have no network
>   access). From 18.03 onwards our recommendation is to connect to the
>   special DNS name host.docker.internal, which resolves to the internal
>   IP address used by the host.
>
> This is for development purpose and will
>   not work in a production environment outside of Docker Desktop for
>   Windows.

Comment: ```port 45678 on the Docker VM is forwarded to port 45678 in server```

what do you mean by server? Windows machine or Container?

Comment: Are you saying that ```-p 45678:45678 ``` means 
```windows-host-port/docker-vm-port : container-port```

Comment: I meant the conatiner called server. In docker for windows when publishing port 45678 on container A you get `<my-windows-hostname>:45678 -> <docker VM>:45678 -> ContainerA:45678`

I have updated my answer to clarify those two points

Comment: Which means whatever port I give to for my host, docker will always use the same port for docker VM as well? They both cant be different like container port.

Comment: Yes, it is the same, but wether it is the same port or not should be irrelevant from a user point of view. The Docker VM is an intermediate layer existing because linux containers cannot run natively on windows. How that intermediate step is handled is internal to the implementation of docker for windows. The key is that the port on the host running the docker cli (windows) has its  port forwarded to the specified container port. Any intermediate steps are completely internal and transparent.

Comment: Thanks for all the insight. Is there any good book that you suggest on docker? so that I can enlighten myself with more such knowledge?

Comment: Not any books in particular, I suggest starting out with the Docker for windows documentation. Also this article does a good job describing Docker for Mac. It differs from the windows implementation in some areas, but the principles with a VM running the actual containsers are similar: https://collabnix.com/how-docker-for-mac-works-under-the-hood/

Answer (score 0):

When you start Docker, a default bridge network (also called bridge) is created automatically, and newly-started containers connect to it unless otherwise specified.

So when you started your container, it was connected to the default bridge network.

Also, containers on the default bridge network can only access each other by IP addresses, unless you use the `--link` option, which is considered legacy.

What `host.docker.internal` does is that it resolves to the internal IP address used by the host (which changes frequently).

[Reference](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/#differences-between-user-defined-bridges-and-the-default-bridge)

Comment: Your answer was also quite helpful, especially your reference. Thanks.